# position image right of list

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to show for each element of an ul list an image on the right side (a photo). This photo is a thumbnail link to the actual photo. The list itself contains 1 up to 4 lines of text. The total available width is something like 600 to 800 px.

This is what I tried, but the clear does not go below the image, thus the next list item does not start below the previous image:

```
<div style="float:right; width:80px;">
    <a class="thickbox" href="2013.jpg" ><img src="2013.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<ul>
    <li>Some long text spanning across several lines. Some long text spanning across several lines. Some long text spanning across several lines. </li>
</ul>

<div style="clear: right; float:right; width:80px;">
    <a class="thickbox" href="2014.jpg" ><img src="2014.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<ul>
    <li>Some long text spanning across several lines. Some long text spanning across several lines. Some long text spanning across several lines. </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works as expected fine http://jsfiddle.net/PAt3V/

Comment: Make you image 10 times large and it wont.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're treating the text and image as a group it makes sense to wrap them in an element like a div, and then clear that.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PAt3V/3/)**

```
<div class="clear">
    <div style="float:right; width:80px;"> <a class="thickbox" href="2013.jpg"><img src="http://www.placekitten.com/80/200" /></a>

    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>Some long text spanning across several lines. Some long text spanning across several lines. Some long text spanning across several lines.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="clear">
    <div style="clear: right; float:right; width:80px;"> <a class="thickbox" href="2014.jpg"><img src="http://www.placekitten.com/80/200" /></a>

    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>Some long text spanning across several lines. Some long text spanning across several lines. Some long text spanning across several lines.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: +1. I suggest removing `clear: right;` from the second image div, as well. It is no longer necessary.

Comment: Not possible, `clear both` moves all elements down in my website. Basically `clear: left` must not be used.